# Can I reset htop settings to defaults *within htop*

Tags: htop

I change htop settings by accident from time to time, and sometimes I don't know what I've changed.  It's really easy when just about every key changes a setting.

Is there any way to reset the settings to defaults within htop, ie without having to find the config files in my profile and manually clear them?

Comment: `chmod a-w ~/.config/htop` will make htop config directory unwritable by all users. So if you change any config by pressing some buttons when using htop, the new config will not be wrote/stored into the config file, so next time you open htop it will go back to original config. Note in the past `chmod a-w ~/.config/htop/htoprc` also works, but it seems htop new version 3.3.0 makes it not working, I'm not sure why, I suspect "Write configuration to temporary file first" in changelog is the reason (https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/blob/207db2e8f8874de7b8cfe43fa5ce7cb7c06b5097/ChangeLog#L19).